# How VPD is accessed via SMBus/I2C?

Tags: linux

Similar to what IPMI is querying, how will I access VPD of every device in a target server via SMBus/I2C?
Do I need a driver for this or the i2c-dev module is enough?
How to verify which is which on a target bus if I have several storage devices connected to a server?

I am using i2cdetect to verify i2c bus, however, I can't verify which bus my device is connected or does it have a bus in the first place. I know for a fact that I need an i2c bus/adapter to determine the actual i2c device. Creating an i2c client can do so but I still need to verify its bus connection and, creating an i2c client makes it limited to define i2c devices as enumerated in the id_table. As much as possible I want it to detect all storage devices regardless if it does have an i2c device or not.

Any replies will be appreciated. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (as the question is old, asking for details is difficult):

If the VPD of your devices is stored in a standard EEPROM, then *likely* the standard EEPROM drivers will suffice. (And if it's accessed in a different way, then I don't know).

`modprobe i2c-dev` will allow I2C access from userspace, which you'll probably already have done if you can use `i2cdetect`. `modprobe eeprom` will install the standard EEPROM driver, probe all busses for devices supported by it, and allow access to the EEPROM's data in `/sys/bus/i2c/drivers/eeprom`.

> However, I can't verify which bus my device is connected or does it have a bus in the first place.

Yes, this is a bit of a pain, and you'll have to know your hardware well and make some guesses based on what devices you can see on the busses.

Looking at

```
/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/name
/sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-*/device/driver/
```

will also help.